# How to use revised array again in loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below code is about, dividing the even elements of list  by 2 till if reaches 1 if the element is odd then remove the element .

I just now started this program. What doubt I have means I need to use the revised array again in the loop. But it showing error.

```
Input:

   4 
   32 60 8 200


Needed Output:

  16 30 4 100
    8 15 2 50 
    4 1 25
    1 





 n=int(input())
    l=list(map(int,input().split()))
    leg=len(l)
    rv=[]
    
    for i in range(0,leg):
      if l[i]%2==0:
        rv.append(l[i]//2)
        l=rv
```

error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HelloWorld.py", line 7, in <module>
    if l[i]%2==0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In my above code what i am trying to do means i append the even elements of list 'l' to 'rv'
and i need to use 'rv' for the loop instead of 'l' but it showing error why??

Comment: Are you sure that the shown code causes the error? Better copy & paste it into the question (with the right indentation).

Comment: sir its showing l[i] out of range

Comment: The given code doesn't raise any error of that kind. Please give a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Its raising l[i] out of range error

Comment: @Heisenberg This makes sense now. But isn't the output missing a second-to-last line "2 1"? And: Fix the indentation of your code!

Comment: @MichaelButscher   No sir what doubt i have means how to use the 'rv 'list again in the same loop instead of using 'l' list

Comment: The above code is not the full code of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this code calculates what you want correctly. However, it breaks if not all the numbers are divisible by two.

```py
n = int(input('set lenght of input'))
l = []

for k in range(n):
    l.append(int(input()))

running = True

while(running):
    print(l)
    for i in l[len(l)-n:len(l)]:
        if(i % 2 == 0):
            z = int(i / 2)
            l.append(z)
            if z == 1: running = False

l = l[n+1:]
print(l)
```